# Global interceptor - runs before every action

Tags: struts2, interceptor

How can I create an interceptor that will run before EVERY action in my application, without the need to specify it for every action separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/how-do-we-configure-an-interceptor-to-be-used-with-every-action.html:

Create your own named stacks and declare a new default interceptor stack for a package

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" >
  <interceptors>
       <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
          <interceptor-ref name="timer"/>
          <interceptor-ref name="logger"/>
        <interceptor-ref name="default-stack"/>
       </interceptor-stack>
  </interceptors>

 <default-interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>

 <action name="login"  class="tutorial.Login">
        <result name="input">login.jsp</result>
        <result type="redirect-action">/secure/home</result>
  </action>

</package>
```

Comment: While this is correct, I'd feel more comfortable with a link that isn't years old.

Comment: @DaveNewton Updated the link to a newer version of struts2 as suggested.

Comment: Better link http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-configure-an-interceptor-to-be-used-with-every-action.html.